# Getting an href from the source code of a webpage

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, href

I am starting on Google Apps Script, and having some difficulties.

I am trying to get automatically an `href` from a specific word in a website.
I already have the word from which I need to extract the `href`.

It is something like:

```js
function substituir_arquivo(nome,logsheet){
  var pagina = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.aaaaaaaa.com/zzz", "site");
  var texto = pagina.getContentText()
  var local = texto.findText(nome)
  var url = 
  log(logsheet, nome, local, url)
}
```

In this webpage, the text that contains "nome" is like that (in this case "nome" = Arquivo):

```html
<a href="http://www.aaaa.com/zzzzz/file " target="_blank" download=""> Arquivo</a>
```

I would like to copy this `href` to the `var url`.

Comment: Mentioning what specific difficulty you are having would be helpful to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Usually `DOM` parsers look for `tag` names not for `HTML` content.
You will have to build your text parser in order to achieve this. Since `HTML` is structured it is easy to parse the `<a/>` tag starting from its content.

### Code

For simplicity I will assume that the given `HTML` content you want to get is unique.

Here is an example of this kind of parser in Apps Script:

```js
function substituir_arquivo(nome,logsheet){
  var pagina = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.aaaaaaaa.com/zzz", "site");
  var texto = pagina.getContentText()
  var start = text.search(`<a.+>${nome}<\/a>`)
  var end = text.indexOf(nome)
  var atag = ""
  var url = ""
  for (let i = start; i<end; i++) {
   atag += html[i];
   if (atag.search(`href=".`) > 0) { // When the first character of the href property is reached I will start putting it in a varaible
      if(url.length > 0 && html[i] == '"') { // When I hit the next " symbol I'm done so I can exit from the loop.
         break;
      } else {
         url+=html[i];
      }
    } 
  }
  Logger.log(logsheet, nome, end, url); 
}
```

### Reference

[JS search()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp)

[JS indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

[JS regex](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)